# counting on $4$ pairs of gloves

Tags: combinatorics

There are $4$ different pairs of gloves. $4$ right handed gloves are given randomly to four persons

then $4$ left handed gloves are given.how many ways are possible such that nobody gets the

right (correct)pair of gloves.

$\underline{\bf{My\;\;Try}}::$ Let the $4$ pairs of gloves as $(a,A)\;\;,(b,B)\;\;,(c,C)\;\;,(d,D)$.

Then R.H.S gloves $(A,B,C,D)$ can be distributed as $ = 4!$ ways.

Now I Did not understand How can I distributed L.H.S gloves so that nobody get correct pair of gloves

Help Required.

Thanks

Comment: ATTEMPT ONLY: For each of the 4! options for the RHS gloves, there are 3! options for the LHS gloves, because first you can give the first person any glove accept for the right pair, which is 3 options, then 2, and then 1 for each remaining person. Totally the answer (as I came to it) is $4!*3!$

Comment: There is no easy algorithm for distributing the left gloves so that all "wrong" combinations are achieve, but all matches are avoided, so looking for this approach is not fruitful. However is you look up the terms "derangements" or "rencontres numbers" you will find useful information on this problem.

Comment: You can try also this: The number of ways to give the people the CORRECT pairs is 4!, try to find the total number of ways to give the pairs of gloves away, no restrictions, and then subtract the 4! from the result.

Comment: But answer given as $4! \times 9$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and should) look up *Derangements*. But the numbers here are so small that we can list and count. Let the right gloves be called $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and the matching left gloves be $a,b,c,d$. The right gloves can be distributed between the $4$ people in $4!$ ways.

Once you have done this, line up the right glove holders in the order $A,B,C,D$ and distribute the left gloves at random.

We count the ways in which we can distribute the left gloves so there is no matching pair. If there is no matching pair, left glove $a$ must go  to $B$, $C$, or $D$. We count the number of ways there is no match and $a$ goes to $B$, and multiply the result by $3$.

So $a$ goes to $B$. Maybe $b$ goes to $A$. Then $c$ must go to $D$, and $d$ to $C$. That gives $1$ way.

Maybe $b$ goes to one of $C$ or $D$. We will count the ways in which $b$ goes to $C$, and multiply by $2$. If $a$ goes to $B$, and $b$ to $C$, then $d$ must go to $A$, and $c$ to $D$. That gives $1$ way. Multiply by $2$, since $b$ could have gone to $D$.

We conclude that there is a total of $3$ ways in which $a$ can go to $B$. Multiply by $2$. We get $9$.

Thus for every one of the $4!$ ways to distribute the right gloves among the $4$ people, there are $9$ ways to distribute the left gloves so that no one is happy, for a total of $4!\cdot 9$.

Comment: Thanks André Nicolas Got it. (Nice explanation.) I have got it using Dearrangement formula. (Using Inclusion -exclusion principle)

Comment: For $6$ pairs of gloves, and maybe even for $5$, I would have gone to the general procedure for counting derangements. That technique is very much worth knowing. My feeling was that $4$ was so small that you were perhaps expected to proceed by direct counting, which I tried to do in a reasonably structured way.